# Is there an equivalent of C#'s using T = X.Y.Z import directive in F#?

Tags: f#

In C# I can define an alias for a type by writing

```
using Foo = Full.Name.Space.Of.My.TypeWithAVeryLongName;
```

Within the code file I can from then on refer to my type via `Foo` instead of `TypeWithAVeryLongName` and there is no need to import `Full.Name.Space.Of.My`.

How do I have to change the `open ...` directive in F# to achieve something similar?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can declare a [type abbrevation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/type-abbreviations):

```
type Foo = Full.Name.Space.Of.My.TypeWithAVeryLongName
```

Answer (score 5):

Just some additinal info, if you just want an abbreviation for your type Taylor Wood's answer is the one.

If you want to abbreviate (or change) a module name, you can use:

`module Short = MyVeryLong.Helpers.Container`

where the namespace is defined as

`module MyVeryLong.Helpers.Container` in another place/file/dll. And you can refer to your type as `Short.MyType`.

but this will only work for a module nested in a namespace. To my knowledge you cannot abbreviate pure namespace names.